# How to make text appear straight in a circular layout using CSS?

Tags: css, text, rotation

I have a circular layout with 12 parts, each representing a different emotion. I'm using CSS to position text inside each part and i want to align the text (in each part) so it appears horizontal.

here is how it appears now( also i will change the text with emojis later but first i want to correct the text align
[image]

I tried changing the text rotation but it affected also the rest of my circle.I also to make for each part their own class so i can change it with css but again nothing.

here is the html / css:

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 35em;
  height: 35em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle-links li:not(:last-child) {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

.circle-links li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(15deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(15deg);
  transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(15deg);
  padding-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.feelingText {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.updatedText {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.textarea-title {
  margin-top: -45vh;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.moreFeelings {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 4em;
  width: 20em;
}

.circle-links li:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(210deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(210deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) skewY(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(330deg) skewY(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg) skewY(-60deg);
}

.circle-links li:first-child .text {
  background: green;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(2) .text {
  background: tomato;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(3) .text {
  background: aqua;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(4) .text {
  background: yellow;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(5) .text {
  background: orange;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(6) .text {
  background: purple;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(7) .text {
  background: cyan;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(8) .text {
  background: brown;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(9) .text {
  background: gray;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(10) .text {
  background: pink;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(11) .text {
  background: maroon;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(12) .text {
  background: gold;
}

li.middle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(150, 72, 72);
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .circle {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 15em;
    height: 150em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  li.middle {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(150, 72, 72);
    color: white;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .circle {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .circle {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 30em;
    height: 30em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  li.middle {
    position: absolute;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(150, 72, 72);
    color: white;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .feelingText {
    margin-top: -40vh;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 90vh;
  }
  .textarea-title {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-right: -1vh;
  }
  .moreFeelings {
    margin-left: 37vh;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 4em;
    width: 20em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .circle {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 25em;
    height: 25em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  li.middle {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(150, 72, 72);
    color: white;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .feelingText {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-right: 100px;
  }
  .textarea-title {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-right: 5vh;
  }
  .moreFeelings {
    margin-left: 25vh;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 4em;
    width: 20em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-links">
  <ul class="circle">
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('sad')"     ><div class="text" title="sad"></div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('happy')"   ><div class="text" title=" happy" style="font-size: 40px;">&#128512</div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('bored')"   ><div class="text" title=" bored">boredom</div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('confused')"><div class="text" title="confused">confusion</div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('curious')" ><div class="text" title="curious">curiosity</div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('despair')" ><div class="text" title="despair">despair</div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('anger')"   ><div class="text" title="anger">anger</div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('excited')" ><div class="text" title="excited">excitement</div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('disinterest')"><div class="text" title="disinterested">disinterest</div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('inspiration')"><div class="text" title="inspired">inspiration</div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('interest')"><div class="text" title=" interested">interest</div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('relief')"  ><div class="text" title="relieved">relief</div></li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('neutral')"class="middle"><div title="neutral">neutral</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to rotate the text elements back the other way by the same amount.

Comment: This kind of thing is easier to do in SVG with 100 times less code...

Comment: My recommendation would be to do this with svg, for example with a library like D3.js.

Comment: @MisterJojo   You mean to do the circle with svg?

Comment: yes, svg code is natively supported in the html5 standard. and in your case all this css code becomes useless

Comment: @MisterJojo I didnt know about svg at all  but i am trying to learn it to see if i can replace the css . I want to ask one question. It isnt going to be responsive to all screens right? I am asking because i only know how to make it compatible with css

Comment: As its name suggests, svg is vector; in other words a vector graphic will be displayed in any screen size without loss of quality [=== responsive] + integrated on an html page everything can be manipulated by javascript code, and these graphic elements obey the css.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simplified structure, that is more continuously responsive.

Instead of having breakpoints at various media sizes, set dimensions relative to viewport size (vmin).

This snippet creates 12 elements which have the height of the circle radius, centers them horizontally then rotates each.

The contents of each are then rotated back to make the text horizontal.

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  --w: 80vmin;
  width: var(--w);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  max-width: 35em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle-links li:not(.middle) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  --rot: calc((var(--n) - 1) * 360deg / 12);
  transform: translateX(calc(-50% - 2px)) rotate(var(--rot));
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  width: calc((pi * var(--w) / 12) + 4px);
  height: calc((var(--w) / 2) + 2px);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%);
}

.circle-links li .text {
  --y: 200%;
  transform: translateY(var(--y)) rotate(calc(-1 * var(--rot)));
  transform-origin: center center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: min(16px, 5vmin);
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(1) .text,
.circle-links li:nth-child(2) .text {
  --y: 0;
}

.circle-links li:first-child {
  --n: 1;
  background: green;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
  background: tomato;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
  background: aqua;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
  background: yellow;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(5) {
  --n: 5;
  background: orange;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(6) {
  --n: 6;
  background: purple;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(7) {
  --n: 7;
  background: cyan;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(8) {
  --n: 8;
  background: brown;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(9) {
  --n: 9;
  background: gray;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(10) {
  --n: 10;
  background: pink;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(11) {
  --n: 11;
  background: maroon;
}

.circle-links li:nth-child(12) {
  --n: 12;
  background: gold;
}

li.middle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(150, 72, 72);
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: min(16px, 5vmin);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-links">
  <ul class="circle">
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('sad')">
      <div class="text" title="sad"></div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('happy')">
      <div class="text" title=" happy" style="font-size: 40px;">&#128512;</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('bored')">
      <div class="text" title=" bored">boredom</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('confused')">
      <div class="text" title="confused">confusion</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('curious')">
      <div class="text" title="curious">curiosity</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('despair')">
      <div class="text" title="despair">despair</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('anger')">
      <div class="text" title="anger">anger</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('excited')">
      <div class="text" title="excited">excitement</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('disinterest')">
      <div class="text" title="disinterested">disinterest</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('inspiration')">
      <div class="text" title="inspired">inspiration</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('interest')">
      <div class="text" title=" interested">interest</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('relief')">
      <div class="text" title="relieved">relief</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="updateFeeling('neutral')" class="middle">
      <div title="neutral">neutral</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note: for the single-character emojis the positioning has been made different to the text - it depends on exactly what final positioning you want as to what the translations should be so you'll want to alter those to suit.

Also note that a small increment is added to the width of the rotated elements. this is to prevent tiny gaps appearing, compensating for the 'rounding error' that can appear when CSS is trying to match screen pixels to part CSS pixels.

Comment: So thats what i am trying to accomplish for the text-alignment.(I am using breakpoints because this is for a web/mobile project and i want to fit all of my page content) .The only issue is that this works only on screens >425px. Any tips to what should i change to make it work for all screen sizes?

Comment: I've tested down to 200px and there is no problem (except the emoji is too big). what is the problem that you are seeing?

Comment: I am sorry i didnt phrase it correctly. The problem is for screens sizes >425px. When the size is <425px then it appears as i am trying to make it.

Comment: I’ve tested it up to 1570px and it was fine. Please can you tell me what looks wrong - maybe you still have some media queries hanging around?

Comment: I have not make a change to my code yet i just run the code snippet and then i click on Full Page and all the text is like moved far away from the circle . I dont know how to post a picture as a commnet so i will edit your answer and post it there

Comment: Thanks for the image - something is wrong! Here is the link to your image https://i.stack.imgur.com/s29bz.png What OS/browser are you on and what size viewport? I will take another look tomorrow - currently I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: i am using chrome and 1440px if thats what you mean. Also thank you very much for your time i appreciate it.

Comment: Hello again and sorry to bother you i wanted to ask if you had time to check it again because i had no luck figuring something out